# What is the type of state for menuList styles key in react-select?

Tags: typescript, react-select

I'm trying to add styles for the menuList key in `styles` prop of `react-select` but getting the following error:
`Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'MenuListComponentProps<{}>'.  TS2339`

Relevant code:

```
import { CSSProperties } from "react";
import Select, { MenuListComponentProps } from "react-select";

<Select 
  ...
  styles={{
    menuList: (base: CSSProperties, state: MenuListComponentProps<{}>) => ({
      "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
        background: state.theme.colors.primary25,
      },
    }),
  }}
/>
```

What should the correct type be for `state` in the above code if not `MenuListComponentProps`?

Answer (score 0):

I found in [code](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/styles.js)

if i'm not wrong it looks like there is nothing left like to do the same

```
// TODO: flow for state
type StyleFn = (props: Props, state: { [key: string]: any }) => {};

export type Styles = {
  clearIndicator?: StyleFn,
  container?: StyleFn,
  control?: StyleFn,
  dropdownIndicator?: StyleFn,
  group?: StyleFn,
  groupHeading?: StyleFn,
  indicatorsContainer?: StyleFn,
  indicatorSeparator?: StyleFn,
  input?: StyleFn,
  loadingIndicator?: StyleFn,
  loadingMessage?: StyleFn,
  menu?: StyleFn,
  menuList?: StyleFn,
  menuPortal?: StyleFn,
  multiValue?: StyleFn,
  multiValueLabel?: StyleFn,
  multiValueRemove?: StyleFn,
  noOptionsMessage?: StyleFn,
  option?: StyleFn,
  placeholder?: StyleFn,
  singleValue?: StyleFn,
  valueContainer: StyleFn,
};
```